# App ID not Available for Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, deployment

I am logged into my developer.app.com and have an "App ID" which includes a wild card.

1. I now go to "Provisioning Profiles" to create a provisioning profile with the wild card App ID.
2. I choose "In House" distribution and click "continue.
3. I arrive on a screen where I can't choose my wild card "App ID".

On the page where I can't choose my app ID in step 3 there is a message which says:

"If you plan to use services such as Game Center, In-App Purchase, and Push Notifications, or want a Bundle ID unique to a single app, use an explicit App ID. If you want to create one provisioning profile for multiple apps or don't need a specific Bundle ID, select a wildcard App ID. Wildcard App IDs use an asterisk (*) as the last digit in the Bundle ID field. Please note that iOS App IDs and Mac App IDs cannot be used interchangeably."

This message is telling me that I can use a wild card App ID for "In House" distribution but I can't select it.

How do I select use a wild card App ID for an In House distribution?